# Today is the square-root of 25th day of the omer

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, mathematics

If you haven't counted sefirat haomer yet that night, you're not supposed to say the current day (for example, 'today is the 5th day') before making the bracha. But what about saying what today is in an indirect manner, such as, 'today is the square-root of 25th day', or 'today is the 10 minus 5th day'?

Comment: How is this diff then saying today is the 10th day minus 5

Comment: The 14th and two weeks is the same thing,so why wouldn't square root be

Comment: @sam So you can be Yotzei days by just counting weeks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is why we say "yesterday was the fourth day" before counting. You do not want to say "today is" in any way because even in an indirect manner you are counting today. Once you have said "today is" then however you say the number, that is still a count.

"Code of Jewish Law Ganzfried - Goldin, volume 3 page 52 chapter 120 number 3 (translation of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch). Any mention of the current number forbids the bracha. This is lechatchila. There is an answer that you can say it b'diavad.

[Advance notice of the day of the Omer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/advance-notice-of-the-day-of-the-omer?rq=1) quotes the Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 489:4

There are those that say that you can express the count using a math problem and still say it with a bracha. The reason appears to be that you are in effect saying that you do not want to be yotzi with what you are saying.  See [Counting Sefiras ha-Omer Unintentionally](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5770/achareimos.html) Note that the implication of what is written below seems to be that if you say the bracha and then count in one of the ways written below, then it is considered a valid count.

> **Question:** If, inadvertently, one forgot and responded with the correct
> sefirah count, is there any way that he can count again that night
> with the blessing?
>
> **Discussion:** B’diavad, one is permitted to recite sefirah that night
> with the blessing:
>
> - If he responded by saying just the correct number of that day, but
>   did not say “Today is number so-and-so,” then he may repeat the
>   sefirah with a blessing[5]. But if he omitted just the word “ba-Omer”
>   (or “la-Omer”), then the count remains valid and it may not be
>   repeated with the blessing[6].
> - If he responded by saying, “Today is so-and-so” but did not mention the “weeks” count, he may still repeat the sefirah with a blessing.    For instance, on the seventeenth day he responded, “Today
>   is day number seventeen,” but he did not add, “which is two weeks
>   and three days.”[7] [Obviously, this applies only after the first
>   week of sefirah has passed.]
> - Even if he responded with the correct number and the right weekly count but had specific and clear intention not to fulfill
>   the mitzvah of Sefiras ha-omer with his response, then he may
>   repeat the sefirah with a blessing[8].
> - If the person who inadvertently forgot and responded, “Today is so and so” is one who is always particular to count the Omer after tzeis ha-kochavim only, and this exchange took place before tzeis ha-kochavim, he may repeat the count with the blessing[9].
> - **If on the fifth day, for example, he responded, “Today is six minus one,” or, “Today is three plus three,” he may repeat the count with the blessing[10] Be’er Moshe 3:82.**
> - If in response to the question he wrote down the correct sefirah    count (but did not say it), he may repeat the sefirah with
>   the blessing[11].
> - If the questioner, for example, asked, “Is today day number five?”    and the response was, “Yes, it is,” then both the questioner
>   and the respondent can repeat the sefirah and recite the blessing[12].

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is true?  Maybe saying "yesterday was..." is just one of the possible indirect ways of saying what today is and any of those indirect ways does not count as counting today. So saying "Today is the square-root of 25 day" could maybe be the same as "yesterday was the 4th day"

Comment: @Daniel That is why I included the pointer to the other question. As long as you say "today is" you have counted. That is also the way we learned from other sources as well.  For example "Code of Jewish Law Ganzfried - Goldin, volume 3 page 52 chapter 120 number 3 (translation of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch). Any mention of the current number forbids the bracha.

Comment: Do you have the source in the real Shulchan Aruch? And you haven't said the number; you've given a math problem to the answer.

Comment: How is square root of 25 a mention of 5?

Comment: @Scimonster I gave the kitzur shulchan aruch quote from the translation as that was easiest to look up and I am having trouble finding it in my copy of the Mishna Brurah. I am addig another reference from Torah.org

Comment: @DoubleAA The square root of 25 is 5. Thus if you say "Today is the square root of 25 days in the omer, that is the count of 5.

Comment: @sabbahillel (The square root of 25 is also -5. The count is ambiguous. In any event,) your assertion that "[t]he square root of 25 is 5" is exactly what the question is asking and you haven't sourced your assertion.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question was if one says "Today is 5" using a math problem such as "Today is the square root of 25 day of the omer" , is that considered counting as if you said it directly or not. The kitzur shulchan aruch appears to say that is is the same. I also found a different reference that seems to say that lechatchila you should not repeat it with a bracha but b'diavad you can. Note that the Torah.org reference seems to say that if you intended to count in that way, you would be yotzi. That is if you said the bracha and then counted in that way it would be valid.

Comment: @sabbahillel The Kitzur (as you quoted it) says "Any mention of the current number forbids the bracha." You have yet to demonstrate that "The square root of 25" counts as a "mention of the current number".

Comment: @DoubleAA That is why I added the Torah.org reference which quotes the Be'er Moshe 3:82 Please check the entire article to see all the footnotes.

Comment: Would you say that counting in base 7 is a mention of the current number? What about counting in weeks?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would have to ask a rav who is an expert in the matter as to how far a kinui (hint) goes.By weeks do you mean something like "3 and 3/7 weeks"? Again all I can say is the reference to the Be'er Moshe as a Bedi'avad. Anything further I cannot say.

Comment: @sabbahillel What do you mean an expert in the matter? You want to know what he'll make up? Or to find sources?

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant someone who will be able to say what other sources will consider "like" 26 - 1 or Lag Baomer as far as hinting goes and what hints are sufficiently remote to allow the bracha lechatchila. I do not have additional sources to quote.