# Counting Omer - yesterday was the day before today

Tags: halacha, blessing, sefirat-ha-omer

If someone asks me which night of the Omer it is tonight, and I answer by telling them that last night was the night before the 5th night (on the 5th night), can I still count with a blessing?

---

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37329/4794) (although not inspired by - just reminded of)

Comment: And why shouldn't the answer be the same? דהיינו We have no Mitzva to count "last night was the night before the 5th"

Comment: Consider too: "Last year was 5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mishnah Berurah (489:20) quotes the Taz who says that since the *mitzvah* is to count "today" any response which doesn't include that word is okay. For example, if someone asks what night it is, and you say, "the fifth night of the Omer," you may still count with the blessing.

Presumably, the same would apply here, since you're not mentioning "today."

Comment: Additionally, from day 7 and onwards, you can still count with a blessing if you didn't say the 'days and weeks' part of the counting. i.e. if you only say 'today is day 23 of the Omer' without saying 'which is 3 weeks and 2 days', you can still count with a Bracha.